# Event Delegation Directive

Tags: javascript, performance, angular.js

In use cases where web applications utilize `ng-repeat` heavily and also rely on event triggers for each item in the collection, such as `ng-click` and the like, watchers become too numerous and may adversely affect performance when the number of items grow large.

To remedy this problem, an event delegation directive could handle the work. It is unfortunate that AngularJS does not support this as a built-in feature, but perhaps they might include it in a future release. Please review my code example for such a directive and point out any areas for improvement or if there's a better implementation.

*Note*: This example assumes that the view model (not shown) contains an array of `items` and a function called `doSomething`.

*Update*: [Here](http://jsbin.com/vunuqupudike/1/edit?html,js,output) is a working example in JSBin to illustrate its use.

**Markup**

```
<ul evt-delegate="doSomething(item)" evt-selector="li">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Code**

```
(function () {
  angular.module('myModule').directive('evtDelegate', ['$parse', delegateDirective]);

  function delegateDirective($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        selector: '='
      },
      link: link
    };

    function link(scope, element, attributes) {
      var selector = attributes.evtSelector,
          expression = attributes.evtDelegate,
          expressionHandler = $parse(expression);

      element.on('click', function (e) {
        var targetNode, targetScope;

        targetNode = getTargetNode(element[0], e.target, selector);

        if (targetNode) {
          targetScope = angular.element(targetNode).scope();

          targetScope.$apply(function () {
            expressionHandler(targetScope);
          });
        }
      });
    }

    function getTargetNode(parent, child, selector) {
      if (!parent || !child) {
        return null;
      }

      if (!selector) {
        return child;
      }

      if (parent === child) {
        // we traveresed all the way up to the parent node, so return
        // null since the selector does not exist as a child
        return null;
      }

      // we cannot trust that child.nodeName is uppercase, 
      // so we make sure it is before doing the comparison
      if (child.nodeName.toUpperCase() === selector.toUpperCase()) {
        return child;
      }

      return getTargetNode(parent, child.parentNode, selector);
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Greetings, awesome question, in my experience you will get the best feedback if you set up a working jsbin/fiddle/plnkr with this.

Comment: Also, cant you just let the `ng-click` bubble up to the ul level ?

Comment: @konijn A JSBin example has been added (see above). The point of event delegation is to not need an `ng-click` directive on each `<li>` element.

Answer (score 1):

I am puzzled by how you use `item` both inside and outside `ng-repeat`.

Each iteration of `ng-repeat` has its own scope, so its own `item`. For instance, if `items = [item1, item2]`, which item do you mean to use inside `doSomething`? 
The way it is used now, the `item` seen by that function will be another `item` on the outside scope. If this is the intention, this variable should be named differently:

```
<ul evt-delegate="doSomething(outsideItem)" evt-selector="li">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

---

UPDATE. Having another look I see better what you are trying to achieve. Still I would improve design by making the directive more re-usable.

You basically want to throw any HTML inside the directive and pick the `model` associated with event's target. The directive makes this `model` available on the scope of your expression `doSomething(model)`.  Just like `$event` made available inside the `ng-click`. I would then mark this `model` as something special like:

```
<ul evt-delegate="doSomething($my-target-model)">
```

Then it is the job of the directive to pick the right model and make it available under this name. This way I can change `item` to `my-item` inside `ng-repeat` without breaking things, so the directive is more encapsulated and re-usable.

Comment: I admit it seems confusing, but `item` does not refer to anything until the event occurs and the expression is parsed by `$parse` in the `link` function of the directive. Only then is the scope determined and only then does `item` refer to the element in the `items` collection that was clicked on.

Comment: The JSBin example does work. I'm not sure what issue you are having with it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are trying to achieve. But can't you just use `jQuery`s event delegation? For some reason, your `JSBin` had auto-run disabled, after I enabled it, it works.

Comment: Yea, I could, but I'm avoiding `jQuery` and attempting to use an AngularJS-only implementation.